# 'TopLevelDocumentMetaclass' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am very new to django world and I try to do some example to use it with mongodb. To connect to mongo I am using mongoengine 0.9.0. I am also using virtualenv.

At the moment I have pretty basic stuff, I am able to run the server but when I try to visualize the webpage I get this error:

```
'TopLevelDocumentMetaclass' object is not iterable.
```

I was checking others entries with similar "object is not iterable" but most of them was with user models of models.py, mine is in the sites.py and for the moment I prefer not to modify it until I know what I am doing :S

Here are my install packages:

- Django==1.5.1
- django-shortcuts==1.5
- djangotoolbox==1.8.0
- mongoengine==0.9.0
- pymongo==2.5.2

My models.py looks like this

```
from mongoengine import *
from mongoengine import connect
connect('mydatabase')

class Restaurant(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length=200)
```

And the only view I have in the views.py file is this one

```
def admin(request):
    html = "<html><body>Proyecto de ejemplo</body></html>"
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

If I don't use mongoengine in my Models.py and instead I use models from django.db it works fine, so I assume that the cause of the problem should be using mongoengine.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Any reason you're using 1.5 in 2019?

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like `'TopLevelDocumentMetaclass' object is not iterable.` is raised by `mongo-engine` while it tries to register model in `django.contrib.admin` so basically mongo got a problem with Django admin.

it seems like registering model like this might help now:

```
admin.register(MyModel)
```

- https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine/issues/208#issuecomment-479284270